# How to write ASCII string to file using Windows API WriteFile?

Tags: c++, c, windows, file-io

I know we can use `WriteFile` to write something to a file:

```
BOOL WINAPI WriteFile (HANDLE hFile, 
                       LPCVOID lpBuffer, 
                       DWORD numOfBytesToWrite,
                       LPDOWRD lpNumOfBytesWritten,
                       LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped);
```

But how can we write ASCII string to a file using this function?

Comment: It writes "a buffer of bytes" (specified via `lpBuffer`). Thankfully ASCII maps well to bytes ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually something like this:

```
WriteFile(your_file, your_string, strlen(your_string), &written, NULL);
```

You usually don't want to do this though -- unless your strings are pretty long, it'll almost always be more efficient (i.e., faster) if you use something like `fprintf` or `fputs` to take advantage of the buffering built into the standard library.